# Import Numpy Package for IronPython

Tags: c#, python, numpy, ironpython

So I'm building an app using C# that requires calling a python script which needs to import numpy. My python version is 3.6 and I am running IronPython 2.7 (64-bit). This is the error I'm getting. "Original error was: cannot import multiarray from numpy.core". Is there any way I can reference Numpy? I've looked everywhere and I genuinely cannot find a solution. The enthought solution is no longer available from previous answers. This is my code.

```
    ScriptRuntime scriptRuntime = Python.CreateRuntime();
    ScriptEngine scriptEngine = scriptRuntime.GetEngine("py");

    var paths = scriptEngine.GetSearchPaths();
    paths.Add(@"C:\Users\minhaj\source\Workspaces\Python\PythonProject\env\Lib");
    paths.Add(@"C:\Users\minhaj\source\Workspaces\Python\PythonProject\env\Lib\site-packages");
    paths.Add(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib");
    scriptEngine.SetSearchPaths(paths);

    dynamic pythonScript = scriptRuntime.UseFile(path);
    dynamic pythonMethod = pythonScript.hello();
```